# How to install SiS 671/771 Video Drivers in ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, video, sis-graphics

Does sis have any drivers available for their 671/771 "video card" ?
how can i install it and set it to 1280x800 resolution?

Comment: See also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124076/where-do-i-get-a-sis-mirage-672-vga-driver) for information on the current situation regarding SiS drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy how-to:
http://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/sis

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for 10.04 and 10.10(not sure of above)
First download the drivers
Use http://ajoliveira.com/ajoliveira/gen...t_10.04.tar.gz for the 32 bit driver and
http://ajoliveira.com/ajoliveira/gen...t_10.04.tar.gz for the 64 bit driver,
 (take the install files), unzip them  once unzipped copy or move them

Open up a terminal and go to the path you've unzipped them in.(use the cd command to navigate to directory's) i.e; cd /home/user/Downloads

`sudo cp sis671_drv.* /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/`

type in your password and press enter

then stop X
(We need to stop X or we won't be able to auto-generate a xorg.conf.new)

`sudo service gdm stop`

(you'll have to do next part blindly)

Code:
`Switch to tty1 by pressing Ctrl+Alt+f1`
 (f2 for tty2, f3 for tty3, etc.. (f7 should be X)

Even though you won't be able to read it (yet) you can login
`type in your username and press enter`

`type in your password and press enter`
Now you're logged in you want to become root; type;

`sudo bash`

`type in your password`

Now your root; type in

`Xorg -configure`
(this will create a xorg.conf.new in your home directory)

and start gdm again with

`service gdm start`

Once there; Open up a terminal again;

move the auto-generated xorg.conf.new to /etc/X11/xorg.conf
 with

`sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
and restart gdm by typing;

`sudo service gdm restart`

Fix the plymouth and the unreadable tty problem like this
 Open up a terminal and typ

`sudo bash`

`enter your password`
type;

`echo blacklist vga16fb > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-vga16fb.conf`
type

`update-initramfs -u`

and reboot `reboot`

After this if you do not have proper resolution then

Once you get to the desktop, start a Terminal and

`cd /etc/X11`
 `sudo nano xorg.conf`
That will open xorg.conf in order to be edited, find "Device" Section and set `Driver "sis671"` (If you're beginner do not change anything else). Now to exit and save make ^x, where ^ means CTRL.... in a few words CTRL-x will let you exit nano, remember to SAVE changes!