# How to enable 3D acceleration with Sis Vga 771/671 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics, 3d, sis-graphics

It's been a while since I configured a good resolution with my sis vga 771/671.

How can I enable the 3D acceleration with this video card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question, but I'll explain (with my story) why it's not currently possible with this particular SiS hardware.

I have been trying to get hardware acceleration working on SiS chipsets, but have never succeeded; 2D acceleration and video acceleration seem to work well. In your `xorg.0.log`, you will probably have a similar error as this:

```
AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI capable
```

This means that DRI is disabled: DRI is known as Direct Rendering Infrastructure and is the [rendering standard](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/) used on Linux based systems for 3D acceleration by such means as opengl. However, the open source driver does not support it and there are unfortunately no ***proprietary*** drivers for the SiS hardware: the source code and specifications have never been released.

Thomas Winischofer was the man who thankfully contributed the code so that SiS adapters can actually work in Linux based systems; his site is [here and contains useful technical information](http://www.winischhofer.net/linuxsisvga.shtml) and he particularly mentions [here](http://www.winischhofer.net/linuxsispart1.shtml#13) that

> There is no DRI/OpenGL/3D support for the SiS 6326, 5597/5598, 530/620, 315, 550, 650, 651, 740, 330, 661, 741, 760, 761 including all model variations with letters in the model number.

Again, at the [freedesktop site](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/SiS?highlight=%28CategoryHardwareVendor%29) it is noted that there are no available DRI drivers for your model unfortunately. It is seen as a wishlist item rather than a bug at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-sis/+bug/44627) because it won't be worked on by the Ubuntu developers, but it is up to those at the [dri project](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/SiS) and others. However it is very unlikely that a suitable driver will be produced because the source code has never been released by SiS.