# My Ubuntu is a slower than Windows, what could be causing this lack of performance?

Tags: 12.10, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I get a SIS mirage 672 vga driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124076/where-do-i-get-a-sis-mirage-672-vga-driver)

I have recently moved to Ubuntu, following some tutorials on internet I have installed a 12.10 version of ubuntu in a partition and it went very well. In the other partition is Wndows 7. Both were installed the same day and I have no other files, such as music, videos etc. It happens that Ubuntu is very slow at working (to open programs etc), and when there are more than two opened it gets even slower and sometimes gets frozen when a message appears saying that Compiz had to be closed. Although it is working well Windows is a little faster.

My PC is a laptop with 320GB HD, 4GB RAM, Intel Core 2 Duo 2.1 Ghz.

Another question is that the higher resolution for video I can get is 1024, while on windows it is 1280.

Please help me, I don't know what else I can do to make my Ubuntu install faster.

output of command `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671  
PCIE VGA Display Adapter [1039:6351] (rev 10)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:0801]
03:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller 
[197b:2382]
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What graphics card do you have (please post the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga` from a terminal) and did you install suggested drivers using the "Additional Drivers" system application? Please update your question with this information by *editing* it.

Comment: Considering that your processor is DUAL CORE 2.1 Ghz, I think its just normal that to process things up taking a little bit more time. About your display, check if your display driver is perfectly installed. One more thing, Are you using unity3d? If you are using unity3d you can always move to unity 2d for fast experience. Whats your video card ?

Comment: sorry, it is not dual core but Core 2 Duo 2.1 Ghz. How can I check if my display drivers are installed correctly?

Comment: run the command that @gertvdijk mentioned. Open up the `Additional Drivers` from the DASH and see if it says that the suggested drivers are activated or not. If not activated just activate it.

Comment: I am so sorry I don't know how to do that, please is there any website I can get this information?

Comment: OK. press `CTRL + ALT + t`, it will open the terminal and then copy the command @gertvdijk mentioned and then paste it in the terminal by `SHIFT + CTRL + V` (paste) then press ENTER. There will be something printed on the terminal. Select them --> rightclick --> Copy. And then update your question with the output. Its very simple.

Comment: OK Thanks. Here we go.the output of the command @gertvdijk mentioned is: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter [1039:6351] (rev 10)
 Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:0801]
03:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller [197b:2382]
What to do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity is running in software emulated 3D mode, because your graphical processor is unsupported. This is why ypur system is slow. The only thing you can do is to install Ubuntu 12.04, as it still has unity 2D. Also I found a site for you, which shows you how to install a working driver for your GPU. [Link](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/sis)

SiS and Via GPU-s are poorly supported under linux, usually there is no 3d, and you need some extra work to get them working. (I have Via Unichrome in my laptop and SiS 730S in my old pc.)